# How to merge multiple ODP (Open Document Presentation) files into a single ODP?

Tags: scripting, opendocument

I'm doing some modular presentations divided into several sections.
Each section have it own file.
At the moment when I prepare a presentation I copy manually each section onto a new file.

What I'm looking for is a way to **automat the process**.

Ex:
Here is an example of my sections files:

```
Title1.odp
Title2.odp
Section1-A.odp
section1-B.odp
section1-C.odp
section2-A.odp
section2-B.odp
```

What I would like is to **automate the merging process** using a script.
Some thing like this:

```
mergeOdpFile.sh if=Title1.odp,Section1-A.odp,Section2-A.odp of=Beginner.odp

mergeOdpFile.sh if=Title2.odp,Section1-A.odp,Section1-B.odp,Section1-C.odp,Section2-A.odp,Section2-B.odp of=Advance.odp
```

I've found several tools to do it online but the thing is that I don't want to send my presentations that have sensitive information to online services. I need to do this **offline**.

I've found this **ooopy** (python script) but it only work for ODT
https://sourceforge.net/projects/ooopy/

Any lead on how to achieve this would be appreciated,

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing at the moment.